# Android how to use JSON with HTTP to get image

Tags: json, image, http, parsing

I am a newbie in android programming and I need to link images from the site by Jason and put images and icons and titles and music controlled by the server

```
Example:http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed
```

I need to extract `profile_image_url_https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [parse the JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494328/parsing-json-in-android) and extract the needed information using Java's object model by traversing the keys and indices in the resulting data structure.